# Excel-Generate Total for Pairs that are bi-directional

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have pairs in my data... A-B is equivalent to B-A.  So if my table is

A-B  20
B-D  20
C-F  10
E-F  10
G-H  15
B-A  10
F-E  20

I'm looking for a way to summarize this data so I know that

B-D 20
C-F 10
G-H 15
A-B-B-A 30
E-F-F-E 30

ABBA and EFFE are not important as long as I know A&B's total and E&F's total.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you’re talking about round-trip travel costs,
where costs of the individual legs are unequal
due to one-way roads, tolls, altitude, time zones, winds, and/or currents. 
It doesn’t affect the answer; it just helps to understand the problem.

I also assume that your data is as shown, with the “`A-B`”, “`B-D`”, etc., in Column `A`, and the corresponding numeric values (costs) in Column `B`
(and that all other columns are available).

Set cell `C1` to `=FIND("-", A1)`. 
(Of course if your data start below Row `1`, adjust the row numbers downward accordingly.) 
This finds the hyphen in the one-way route designator.  See note below.

Set cell `D1` to `=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-C1) & "-" & LEFT(A1, C1-1)`. 
This generates the reverse route; e.g., if `A1` is “`A-B`”, `D1` will evaluate to “`B-A`”. 
**Note:** if your Column `A` data are really
all of the form *(single letter) (hyphen) (single letter)*,
then `C` will always be 2, `LEN(A1)` will always be 3,
and you can simplify `D1` to `=RIGHT(A1, 1) & "-" & LEFT(A1, 1)`.

Set cell `E1` to `=IF(A1<D1, A1 & "-" & D1, D1 & "-" & A1)`. 
This generates the round-trip route; e.g., `E1` will evaluate to “`A-B-B-A`”. 
See note below.

Drag/fill the formulas in Columns `C`-`E` down to cover all the data. 
**Note:** Column `E` contains a *sorted* round-trip route,
so `E6` also contains “`A-B-B-A`” (not “`B-A-A-B`”).

Sort by Column `E`.  (You might want to copy your data first; e.g., to another worksheet.) 
Insert a blank row above the data, if there isn’t one there already.

Now set `F2` to `=IF(E2=E3, "", IF(E1=E2, E2, A2))` and `G2` to `=IF(E1=E2, G1+B2, B2)`. 
Drag/fill down to cover all the data.  Your sheet should look like this:

[image: Columns A-G]

Filter on Column `F` and filter out the blanks:

[image: Columns F and G only, filtered]

This doesn’t validate your data. 
If you have multiple rows that say “`P-Q`”,
this solution will simply add them all and report the sum as the total for “`P-Q-Q-P`”.

If you want to sort the one-way routes ahead of the round-trip routes,
that capability can be added.